# Python3 sqlite syntax error when querying with VALUES

Tags: python, sqlite

Python version: 3.6.3
Sqlite version: 3.14.2
(also tested on Python 3.8.10 w/ sqlite 3.35.5)

When I attempt to run a query of the form:

```python
    conn = sqlite3.connect('example_database.db')
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute('SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE ((col1, col2) IN (VALUES (1, 2), (3, 4)))')
```

I get error

```python
    OperationalError: near ",": syntax error
```

This only occurs when the query includes the VALUES keyword:

```python
    cur.execute('SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE col1 IN (1, 3)')
```

runs successfully.

After I tinkered around a bit, it appears that the problematic comma is between col1 and col2:

```python
    cur.execute('SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE ((col1!, col2) IN (VALUES (1, 2), (3, 4)))')
    OperationalError: unrecognized token: "!"

    cur.execute('SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE ((col1,! col2) IN (VALUES (1, 2), (3, 4)))')
    OperationalError: unrecognized token: ","
```

Is the syntax wrong? Is something possibly broken in my environment?

Comment: why do you have so many parens? I've never seen it like that before. Also, I don't think `VALUES` is used here, it should probably just be `SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE (col1, col2) IN ((1,2), (3,4))` but I can't be certain.

Comment: Sorry, I left out some context. I originally found this problem from using peewee, when running a query of the form t1.select().where(Tuple(t1.col1, t1.col2).in_(baz)). The auto-generated SQL was of the above form. I believe I've tracked it down to sqlite itself breaking. It looked like (when examining previous related issues) that this should work? I had [an issue](https://github.com/coleifer/peewee/issues/2426) here, where none of the given code works in my environment, despite working for others.

Comment: Well, I uninstalled and then reinstalled everything and now it works. I still have no idea why.